MongooseError: Operation buffering timed out after 10000ms
Good morning everyone,
I've been working on a school project and I'm having trouble seeding the MongoDB database. When I run the provided code I get a "MongooseError: Operation 'trips.deleteMany()' buffering timed out after 10000ms". I've ensured that my MongoDB is running, I can mongosh and manually manipulate the DB. I've also verified that the DB connects to my DBeaver app for a GUI so I'm not sure why Mongoose appears to be having issues connecting. Following other posts recommendations, I have also attempted to place 'await' commands before the connection attempts and before the deleteMany() attempts.
seed.js

// Brind in the DB connection and the Trip schema
const Mongoose = require('./db')
const Trip = require('./travlr');

// Read seed data from json file
var fs = require('fs');
var trips = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data/trips.json', 'utf8'))

// Delete any existing records, then insert seed data
const seedDB = async () => {
    await Trip.deleteMany({});
    await Trip.insertMany(trips);
};

// Close the MongoDB connection and exit
seedDB().then(async () => {
    await Mongoose.connection.close();
    process.exit(0);
});

db.js // This is the JavaScript file where the connection happens

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const host = process.env.DB_HOST || '127.0.0.1';
const dbURI = 'mongodb://${host}/travlr';
const readLine = require('readline');

// Build the connection string and set the connection timeout.
// timeout is in milliseconds
const connect = () => {
    setTimeout(() => mongoose.connect(dbURI, {
    }), 1000);
}

// Monitor connection events
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log(`Mongoose connected to ${dbURI}`);
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', err => {
    console.log('Mongoose connection error: ', err);
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', () => {
    console.log('Mongoose disconnected');
});

// Windows specific listener
if(process.platform === 'win32'){
    const r1 = readLine.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });
    r1.on('SIGINT', () => {
        process.emit("SIGINT");
    });
}

// Configure for Graceful Shutdown
const gracefulShutdown = (msg) => {
    mongoose.connection.close(() => {
        console.log(`Mongoose disconnected through ${msg}`);
    });
};

//Event Listeners to process graceful shutdowns

// Shutdown invoked by nodemon signal
process.once('SIGUSR2', () => {
    gracefulShutdown('nodemon restart');
    process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGUSR2');
});

// Shutdown invoked by app termination
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    gracefulShutdown('app termination');
    process.exit(0);
});

// Shutdown invoked by container termination
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
    gracefulShutdown('app shutdown');
    process.exit(0);
});

// Make initial connection to DB
connect();

// Import Mongoose schema
require('./travlr');
module.exports = mongoose;

Any help would be appreciated.

Is db.js your own idea or did someone tell you this is how to create a db connection module? The mongoose.connect(dbURI) is inside a setTimeout() function which has a 1 second delay so your seedDB() call is probably executing before you are even connected. Also. why are you exporting mongoose from that module? Surely you want to export a connect function? Regardless, the error tells you mongoose has timed out after 10secs so you probably never connect anyway.

The db.js was provided from the assignment given so I haven't attempted to modify it yet.
